# Gramática de 4 niveles de precedencia. LL(1)

Tags: compilador, parsear

necesito hacerme una gramática con cuatro niveles de precedencia que son los siguientes:

```
1. ** !

2. * / % &

3. + -  ^ |

4. <= >= < >
```

El objetivo es a partir de esto montarme un parser y a continuación el ast. He montado algo de la siguiente naturaleza:

```
Exps -> Exp RExp4

RExp4 -> OpEq Exps | RExp3

RExp3 -> OpAd Exps | RExp2

RExp2 -> OpMul Exps | RExp1

RExp1 -> OpExp Exps | epsilon

Exp -> Val | '('Exps')'

OpExp ->  ** | !

OpMul -> * | / | % | &

OpAd -> + | - | ^

OpEq -> <= | >= | < | >

Val -> Id | Int
```

La cosa está en que no estoy segudo de si esto está bien. Al hacerme el árbol en papel expresiones como la que siguen no se construyen debidamente, básicamente porque coloco la suma por delante de la multiplicación:

```
x*7+7
```

La gramática debe ser recursiva por la derecha y LL(1), debido a que el compilador es btdown.

Un saludo y gracias.